# Node.js using heroku temp directory and nodemailer

Tags: node.js, heroku, fs, nodemailer

I want to save files temporarily to my heroku file system so that I can send them in an email. As long as the email sends with the attachment, I don't care what happens to the file after that.

```
var path = require("path");
var temp_dir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'temp/');
if (!fs.existsSync(temp_dir))
    {fs.mkdirSync(temp_dir);}

request.get({ 
      url: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id='+posting.driveID+'&exportFormat=xlsx', 
      encoding: null,  // Force Request to return the data as Buffer
      headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer "+access_token
      }
      }, function done (err, res) {
        fs.writeFile('temp/temp.xlsx', res.body, function (err) {
          console.log(err);
      })
    });
    var mailOptions={
      from : "",
      to : "",
      subject : "new download",
      generateTextFromHTML : true,
      html : "<h2>Download "+posting.title+"</h2>",
      attachments: [{
            filePath: "temp/temp.xlsx"
      }]
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, resp){
      if(error) {
      }
      else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + resp.message);
      }
      transporter.close();
    });
```

I heard that heroku had the ability to host a /temp directory that wipes itself when the dyno recharges. I have tried to use that but have not had any luck. I receive the email with the temp.xlsx document but it is corrupt with no content. Making wonder if nodemailer cannot find the file so it just makes one with that name.

There is no clear documentation on using heroku's file system so I am wondering where my issue is. Otherwise I may just switch over to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't really do that.  There is a way, but it's unreliable.

Heroku instances are designed to be read only.  This let's you spin up/down as many as you like to scale.

The Heroku way would be to either:

1. Store them in memory (if they are only needed for that instance)
2. Store them in a database (if they are used by all instances)

Note that you can send a stream as an attachment.  You don't need to use an actual file.

```
res.attachment('pdfname.pdf');
someStream.pipe(res);
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.attachment

Comment: The file that I am downloading from Google Drive is the result of an export event:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id='+posting.driveID+'&exportFormat=xlsx

It is not actually a hosted file on google, it must be triggered. Would I still be able to use the stream functionality?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes.  You'll have to look in the documentation for `trasporter` especially around the `attachments` field.  You should be able to send a buffer or stream instead of the filepath.  What you really want to send is `res.body` from the `request.get` response.